# Delphi 10.3 , Anroid (8.1.0) , Zebra TC20 , SSID

Tags: android, delphi, wifi

I am trying to get the SSID but it always returns

```
procedure TMainScreen.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var obj: JObject;
    WifiMgr : JWifiManager;
    WifiInfo : JWifiInfo;

    level : integer;
    SSID : string;
begin
  // ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION Permission

  obj := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiMgr := TJWifiManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);

  WifiInfo := WifiMgr.getConnectionInfo;

  level:=WifiInfo.getRssi;

  SSID := JStringToString(WifiInfo.getSSID);

  Toast('SSID '+SSID+' Signal Strength : '+IntToStr(level), TToastLength.ShortToast);

end;
```

I also tried to

```
  if WifiInfo.getSupplicantState = TJSupplicantState.JavaClass.COMPLETED then
  begin
    SSID := JStringToString(WifiInfo.getSSID);
  end
  else
  begin
    SSID := 'Not Completed';
  end;
```

but it always return `Not Completed`.

**UPDATE 1**

I start the Program without WIFI Connection .

```
 Toast(JStringToString(WifiInfo.getSupplicantState.toString), TToastLength.ShortToast);
```

I get DISCONNECTED .

Then I start the Connect to WIFI , it says SCANNING .

Then I am connected it says CONNECTED .

But why on earth is this not working then ?

```
 if WifiInfo.getSupplicantState = TJSupplicantState.JavaClass.COMPLETED then
```

and this is working

```
  if JStringToString(WifiInfo.getSupplicantState.toString) = 'COMPLETED' then
  begin
    Toast('String Compare', TToastLength.ShortToast);
  end;
```

Comment: well I just allowed the Application on the Android to Access Location Services . And the SSID is returned. But for some reason the getSupplicantState = TJSupplicantState.JavaClass.COMPLETED is not working. So I had to comment it out. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: What does `getSupplicantState()` return if not CONNECTED? Also, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html) says: "*These enumeration values are used to indicate the current wpa_supplicant state. This is more fine-grained than most users will be interested in. In general, it is better to use [NetworkInfo.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html).*" Which itself is deprecated in API 29 in favor of [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Comment: please see UPDATE 1

Comment: I can't answer that. You will have to debug the code for yourself to find out why the enum comparison is not working as expected. I would suggest starting with verifying that `TJSupplicantState.JavaClass.COMPLETED` returns the expected value.